# SQL group-n-result (count, max, group)

Tags: sql, group-by, count, max, amazon-redshift

Using SQL (Redshift)
I'm trying to count, and return the maximum value of each item in a group by. I've tried a number of examples but none have yield the output I wanted. Here is some example data and result I'm after.

Data

```
Container,fruit
box1, apple
box1, apple
box1, apple
box1, apple
box1, banana
box2, blueberry
box2, blueberry
box2, strawberry
box3, apple
box3, apple
box3, blueberry
```

Query Result

```
Container, fruit, count
box1, apple, 4
box2, blueberry,2
box3, apple, 2
```

I've been trying a number of examples out there and not getting anywhere for a few hours, so would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use window functions here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Container, fruit, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Container
                              ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Container, fruit
)

SELECT Container, fruit, cnt
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The logic here is to do a basic `GROUP BY` aggregation query by container *and* fruit, to find the counts for each of these groups.  In the CTE, along the way, we also pick up a row number, this time partitioned only by the container, ordered descending by count.

Comment: Thanks so much Tim. This answer was very similar to others but really helped me out! PM me and I can show some appreciation. (Couldn't see how)